# Jquery chaining syntax

Tags: jquery, delay, mouseenter, mouseleave

What is the correct way to invoke a `mouseenter()` event... pause... `mouseleave()` event?

Something like...

```
$('.some_item').each(function(index) {
    $(this).mouseenter().delay(2000*index).mouseleave();
});
```

...but that doesn't work

[Here's a fiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/8enTg/)

P.s. I don't actually want to change the colour of anything, the fiddle is just an example. It must be `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.some_item').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    });

    $('.some_item').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).css('color', 'green');
    });

    $('.some_item').each(function(index) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.mouseenter();
        setTimeout(function() { $this.mouseleave(); }, 2000*index);
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8enTg/3/

Answer (score 1):

`.mouseenter` can't be delayed. You can use [`.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) to do that

```
$('.some_item').each(function(index) {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.mouseenter().delay(2000*index).queue(function(next){
       elem.mouseleave();
       if (next) next();
    });
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orig/8enTg/2/)

Comment: I've marked nbrooks answer as correct because using setTimeout was more suited to my actual code. Your answer was technically still correct for the question asked. +1. Thanks for your help